# elastic search aggregate doesn't return data

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

It possible that aggregate function returns data instead of count?

Right now I get:

```
array (size=3)
'doc_count_error_upper_bound' => int 0
'sum_other_doc_count' => int 0
'buckets' => 
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => int 15
      'doc_count' => int 2
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => int 14
      'doc_count' => int 1
```

But this is useless cause I need the actual data that represents this doc_count of 2 and doc_count of 1

I'm using elastica.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a query like the following and use [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregations to get the document source.

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "terms_aggregation": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "anyfield",
                "size": 10
            },
            "aggs": {
                "gruped_result": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 100
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think maybe something like this in your php client

```
$termsAgg = new Terms("anyfields");
$termsAgg->setField("anyfield");

$statsAgg = new TopHits();
$statsAgg->setSize(100);

$termsAgg->addAggregation($statsAgg);
$index = $elasticaClient->getIndex('someindex');
$buckets = $index->search($query)->getAggregation("anyfields");
```

I referred [this example](http://elastica.io/example/aggregations/terms.html) for Sub-aggregations on official page

Comment: Can you explain this more I wasn't using this JSON form when creating query. I did it like this http://elastica.io/example/aggregations/terms.html So have would I change this code in the link to use your solution?

Comment: can you share your php query?, i have never used php client.

Comment: with some modifications this worked. Thank you. But why is there a limit of 100. Is there to have unlimited results. I know you can hard code it and write 999999 in it but still.